# caml query to get most popular documents on sharepoint 2013?

Tags: caml, sharepoint-2013

i want to get back all the documents over a site collection that have the biggest number of likes ? How can I do this writing a caml query?
That's what i have tried so far:

```
SPQuery query = newSPQuery();
Query.query = @ "<where> <Eq> <FieldRef Nom= 'NumberOfLikes'/> <ValueType = 'Integer'> 5 </value> </Eq> </where>"
```

This enables me to have the documents that have 5 number of likes but I want those who have the biggest number of likes :s

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user orderbyquery on NumberOfLikes this way you will get document on maximum like on the top.
If you want a limited number of document then you can set a query.rowlimit or if you have nay condition like 5 then you can use as stated all documents gt>5 likes order by likes

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you only get documents which have 5 likes is because you are using the operation . You can use the operator  to get the documents whose likes are more than 5.

There are multiple operators that you can use. They are as follows:

```
Eq                     Equals
===============================================
Neq                    Not equal
Gt                     Greater than
Geq                    Greater than or equal
Lt                     Lower than
Leq                    Lower than or equal too
IsNull                 Is null
BeginsWith             Begins with
Contains               Contains
```

Let me know if this works for you